# Modify configuration file in compiled Inno Setup installer (custom configuration file for each downloaded executable)

Tags: php, linux, inno-setup

I am working on a project which needs a unique method of operation which requires a windows installer exe (packaged using Inno Setup) to be updated with different configuration file containing a unique identification number for every downloads.

The project itself is a web based for which I am using PHP on Apache and on Linux.

The installer contains a Windows binary executable file and `config.ini` file. I just need to edit the `config.ini` file every time the file is to be made ready for download. The updates are simply incremented counter.

I am not finding a direction to approach as I am looking at editing a Inno Setup packaged file created in Windows to be edited in a Linux server.

Can anyone point me towards some ideas to achieve this please.

Thanks,
Sk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Below is an old answer that works only if you do not sing the installer. Nowadays you basically cannot distribute unsigned installers. Skip further below.*

Just store the configuration file to the installer uncompressed to allow easy modification. Use [`nocompression` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=nocompression). You also have to use [`dontverifychecksum` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=dontverifychecksum), otherwise the installer will consider the modified file as corrupted, when installing.

```
[Files]
Source: "config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: nocompression dontverifychecksum
```

You also cannot modify file length. So you need to reserve enough space in the file for larger numbers, like:

```
[Section]
Counter=?????
```

To modify the installer with PHP, you can now do:

```php
$counter = $_GET["counter"];
$filename = "mysetup.exe";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$mask = "?????";
$prefix = "Counter=";
$replace = $prefix . $mask;
$p = strpos($contents, $replace);
if ($p !== false)
{
    $s = $prefix . str_pad($counter, strlen($mask), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $contents =
        substr($contents, 0, $p) . $s . substr($contents, $p + strlen($replace));

    // (or feed directly to the output stream)
    file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
}
```

---

If you sign the installer (these day it is basically necessary for downloadable installers), you have to sign it after modifying it.

Or see [Embed user-specific data into an authenticode signed installer on download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46096886/850848).

---

Another way is to include the custom data into the installer name.

Comment: Awesome.. that works like charm.. Will remember this help for a long long time.. this problem was troubling me for a long time..thank you so much :-)