# Embed user-specific data into an authenticode signed installer on download

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inno-setup, code-signing

I have a Windows Forms application installed using InnoSetup that my users download from my website.  They install this software onto multiple PCs.

The application talks to a Web API which must be able to identify the user.  I am creating a web application where the user can log in and download the app.  I would like to embed a universally unique ID into the installer so that they do not have to login again after installation.  I want them to download and run setup.exe, and have the application take care of itself.

I am considering a couple of options:

1. Embed a user-specific UUID into setup.exe and perform code-signing on-demand on the web server
   Downside: not sure how to do this?
2. Embed a user-specific UUID into the name of the installer file (e.g. setup_08adfb12_2712_4f1e_8630_e202da352657.exe)
   Downside: this is not pretty and would fail if the installer is renamed
3. Wrap the installer and a settings file containing the UUID into a self-extracting zip

How can I embed user-specific data into a signed executable on the web server?

Comment: Use a unique but shorter name Setup_AcmeLtd then during install have inno post out 'AcmeLtd' to an HTTP API that returns the GUID?

Comment: the shorter name may be an option.  However, if installer gets renamed would fail (but I suppose I could step in and ask for customer id / company name at this point).

Comment: I do not see creating a self-extracting archive as an easier solution to implement than 1) and it's certainly less-user friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire PE is not signed.  You can embed data into a signed PE by adding it to the signature table.  This method is [used by Webex and other tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/09/04/caveats-for-authenticode-code-signing/) to provide the one-click meeting utilities.

Technically, the PKCS#7 signature has a list of attributes that are specifically designated as unauthenticated which could be used, but I know of no easy way to write to these fields without a full PE parser.  Luckily, we already have `signtool`, and adding an additional signature to an already signed file is a non-destructive operation that uses the unauthenticated fields.

[I put together a demo](https://github.com/mgaffigan/passdata) which uses this technique to pass data from an MVC website to a downloadable windows forms executable.

The procedure is to:

1. Start with the authenticode signed and timestamped exe produced by standard processes
   (must be able to run without dependencies - ILMerge or similar)
2. Copy the unstamped exe to a temp file
3. Create an ephemeral code signing certificate which includes the auxiliary data as an [X509 extension](http://siber-sonic.com/mac/MailSMIME/X509Extensions.html)
4. Use `signtool` to add the auxiliary signature to the temp file
5. Return the temp file to the client, delete it after the download completes

On the client side, the app:

1. Reads the signing certificates from the currently executing exe
2. Finds the certificate with a known subject name
3. Finds the extension with a known OID
4. Alters its behavior based off of the data contained in the extension

The process has a number of advantages:

- No monkeying with the PE layout
- The publicly trusted code signing certificate can stay offline (or even in an HSM), only ephemeral certificates are used on the web server
- No outbound traffic is generated from the web server (as would otherwise be required if timestamping were performed)
- Fast (<50ms for a 1MB exe)
- Can be run from within IIS

#### Usage

Client side retrieval of data ([Demo Application\MainForm.cs](https://github.com/mgaffigan/passdata/blob/master/Demo%20Application/MainForm.cs))

```
try
{
    var thisPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var stampData = StampReader.ReadStampFromFile(thisPath, StampConstants.StampSubject, StampConstants.StampOid);
    var stampText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stampData);

    lbStamped.Text = stampText;
}
catch (StampNotFoundException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, $"Could not locate stamp\r\n\r\n{ex.Message}", Text);
}
```

Server side stamping ([Demo Website\Controllers\HomeController.cs](https://github.com/mgaffigan/passdata/blob/master/Demo%20Website/Controllers/HomeController.cs))

```
var stampText = $"Server time is currently {DateTime.Now} at time of stamping";
var stampData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stampText);
var sourceFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Demo Application.exe");
var signToolPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/signtool.exe");
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
bool deleteStreamOpened = false;
try
{
    IOFile.Copy(sourceFile, tempFile, true);
    StampWriter.StampFile(tempFile, signToolPath, StampConstants.StampSubject, StampConstants.StampOid, stampData);

    var deleteOnClose = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read | FileShare.Delete, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
    deleteStreamOpened = true;
    return File(deleteOnClose, "application/octet-stream", "Demo Application.exe");
}
finally
{
    if (!deleteStreamOpened)
    {
        try
        {
            IOFile.Delete(tempFile);
        }
        catch
        {
            // no-op, opportunistic cleanup
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to cleanup file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will digest this over the weekend, excellent reply, thanks