# Signed nightly builds for Windows

Tags: installation, sign

For an open-source application we'd like to provide nightly and patched builds from our Jenkins instance for users to test.

Code signing certificates accepted by Windows are only available to registered companies, and can only be used with a smartcard, which makes sense given the impact of a compromised key.

So I'm looking for a way to distribute binaries to users without compromising security, but in a way that is still manageable for us.

Idea 1: ask users to install a certificate

This is inconvenient for the users, but can be done with sensible effort (the "root" certificate would be tied to an off-line key, and the actual signing key would include a CRL URL).

Idea 2: create a downloader tool (similar to Minecraft)

This would be quite a bit of effort to write. Verification would work by checking the signature on the installer package against our signing key, which would be in a separate key store, and we could impose additional sanity checks on the package (e.g. a limited set of MSI actions). Because the downloader tool would seldom change, signing that with a regular code signing certificate is not an issue.

What are best practices for a scenario where automated builds should be made available to large groups of testers that are not part of a single organization?

Comment: This is likely too broad for SO, but Authenticode requires an HSM, not a Smartcard.  Both Azure and AWS provide HSM as a service.  With regards to the MSI wrapper, it is much smaller than you think.  I did one in < 200 lines.  Add a signature to the MSI with a known root, then check that the MSI is signed with a certificate chaining to the root.  If it is, call `MsiInstallProduct` - it really is just one method call.

Comment: See also [Embed user-specific data into an authenticode signed installer on download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096886/embed-user-specific-data-into-an-authenticode-signed-installer-on-download/46105769#46105769)